# How to take user input and place next to similar element in list?

Tags: python-3.x, list, input

*using Python 3.8*
I have a list and I'm trying to ask for 3 inputs from the user e.g

```
list = [7, 5, 3, 2, 2, 1]
```

get 3 inputs e.g 8, 7, 3

Then place them in order e.g *[8, 7, 5, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1]*

So far I attempted like below (just a test), but it adds 7 to the end instead of next to the other 7. I'm just very confused. I know I can use sort, but that's too easy.

```
natural = [7, 5, 3, 3, 2]
entry = 7

for item in natural:
    if entry >= item:
        natural.insert(item, entry)
        break

print(natural)
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is the given list in sorted or random order?

Answer (score 0):

you probably need to define your own `reverse_insert` function like this:
(to simulate `bisect` module)

```
def reverse_insort(a, x, lo=0, hi=None):
    if lo < 0:
        raise ValueError('lo must be non-negative')
    if hi is None:
        hi = len(a)
    while lo < hi:
        mid = (lo+hi)//2
        if x > a[mid]: hi = mid
        else: lo = mid+1
    a.insert(lo, x)

lst = [7, 5, 3, 3, 2]

x = 7

reverse_insort(lst, x)

print(lst)
```

Output:

```
[7, 7, 5, 3, 3, 2]
```